# CustomAction with Postback in SharePoint 2010 (Or another approach?)

Tags: sharepoint-2010, postback, server-side, custom-action

I'm trying to create a custom action that does a postback when clicked in SharePoint 2010.

I've followed the following articles with no luck whatsoever:

1. http://makarandrkulkarni.blogspot.com/2010/01/sharepoint-2010-ribbon-customization_09.html
2. http://blog.dennus.net/2010/07/20/ribbon-buttons-with-postback-in-sp2010/
3. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sridhara/archive/2010/12/30/implementing-a-post-back-button-in-a-sharepoint-2010-web-part-with-contextual-ribbon.aspx

Frankly, article 3 is a ridiculous amount of work just to do a postback so I didn't even attempt it.

I've managed to get the button on the ribbon but without the CommandUIHandler element in the elements.xml the button is forever disabled.

Anyway, this is what I'm trying to achieve:

I have an external list. I want a custom action on the list that updates a field in another database when it is clicked. Now, this doesn't have to be via a postback, I am open to any suggestions anyone has - I just thought doing a postback would be simple, obvisouly I was wrong. This, so I've heard was stupidly easy in SharePoint 2007.

Thanks in advance for any help/suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer on SP OF.

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/11845/custom-action-with-postback-or-another-approach-sp-2010